# Is it possible to mount an SMB1 share and then share it via SMB2 or SMB3?

Tags: networking, mount, samba, aws

We have a Windows Server 2003 (yes, very old) that is our on-premises storage for about 200 GB of content. We want to use AWS DataSync to sync that data into an AWS EFS file system. Unfortunately, AWS DataSync requires at least SMB2, and Windows Server 2003 only supports SMB1.

We are considering standing up an on-premises Ubuntu Linux server (which can use SMB2 or SMB3), and having AWS DataSync talk to that server instead, with that server in turn talking to the Windows Server 2003.

The question I have is, having never touched SMB before yesterday, whether we can mount an SMB1 share from Windows Server 2003 onto Ubuntu, and then turn around and share that very same mount point to AWS DataSync under SMB2 or SMB3?

Or does each folder only get shared under a specific version of SMB, and it would be necessary to make an intermediary copy of the data from Windows Server 2003 onto Ubuntu, with that intermediary copy being made available to AWS DataSync?

I'm also open to other ideas on how to architect this.

Comment: I do not know if it works or not but I think the best way (relatively easy and sure)  to know that is to try it. Try to mount your Windows Server 2003 on your Ubuntu.  Try to share files between Ubuntu and AWS and finallyr try to share the files mounted from windows.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is possible!

We first needed to mount the Windows Server 2003 share with the following in `/etc/fstab`:

`//[IP address of Windows 2003 server]/elearningbuild /smb/elb cifs file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,vers=1.0,username=[redacted],password=[redacted],domain=ama,uid=0,gid=33 0       0`

The `uid` and `gid` are optional (we happen to need them), and it's possible to use a credentials file rather than hardcoding a username and password. However, as everyone who has access to root on the Linux server also has access to the shared account that's accessing the share, we just hard-coded it.

We mounted the share with `sudo mount -a`, which would mount every file system noted in `/etc/fstab`.

Then, we updated `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with:

```
[elb]
comment = This is a reshare of elb
read only = no
path = /smb/elb
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
```

Finally, we restarted Samba with `sudo service smbd restart`.